# Using Ubuntu derivatives *and* Ubuntu, how do I get the Ubuntu codename?

Tags: lsb-release

I need the Ubuntu codename for generating an `apt` source.

On Ubuntu, I can use `lsb_release --codename --short`, which will return (e.g.) `trusty`.

On (e.g.) Linux Mint, if I use `lsb_release -cs`, it returns (e.g.) `rosa`. If I want the upstream codename, I can use `lsb_release -csu` (which returns `trusty`).

However, if I use `lsb_release -csu` on Ubuntu, I get an error  `lsb_release: error: no such option: -u`.

Is there a way to get the upstream-iest Ubuntu codename, including *on* Ubuntu?

Comment: There is no mention of `-u` in http://manpages.ubuntu.com, http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.0.0/LSB-PDA/LSB-PDA/lsbrelease.html, and https://linux.die.net/man/1/lsb_release. So it seems to me that `-u` is a modification of the lsb_release code by Mint developers. Maybe Mint's man pages can shed some light on this option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu trusty doesn't have `UBUNTU_CODENAME` in `/etc/os-release` (it's too old). Mint sylvia dropped support for the `-u` switch to `lsb_release`.

There *is*, on all the versions of Ubuntu and Mint that I've tried, a file called `/etc/lsb-release`, which defines `DISTRIB_CODENAME`. For Mint, it's the Mint codename, but there's also `/etc/upstream-release/lsb-release`, which is the Ubuntu file.

So...

Currently, we're using the following:

```
UBUNTU_CODENAME=$( \
   (grep DISTRIB_CODENAME /etc/upstream-release/lsb-release || \
    grep DISTRIB_CODENAME /etc/lsb-release) 2>/dev/null | \
   cut -d'=' -f2 )
```

Answer (score 5):

On Linux Mint you can source `/etc/os-release` and access the Ubuntu codename that way:

```
source /etc/os-release
echo $UBUNTU_CODENAME # xenial
```

Alternatively, you could extract it with `sed`

```
sed 's/UBUNTU_CODENAME=//;t;d' /etc/os-release # xenial
```

On Linux Mint Sylvia, this is what `/etc/os-release` looks like:

```
NAME="Linux Mint"
VERSION="18.3 (Sylvia)"
ID=linuxmint
ID_LIKE=ubuntu
PRETTY_NAME="Linux Mint 18.3"
VERSION_ID="18.3"
HOME_URL="http://www.linuxmint.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://forums.linuxmint.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint/"
VERSION_CODENAME=sylvia
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial
```

Comment: Doesn't work on trusty; doesn't have `UBUNTU_CODENAME`; you have to do something like this: `UBUNTU_CODENAME=$( (grep DISTRIB_CODENAME /etc/upstream-release/lsb-release || grep DISTRIB_CODENAME /etc/lsb-release) 2>/dev/null | cut -d'=' -f2 )`

Answer (score 1):

You could try running `lsb_release -csu`, checking if it gave output or returned an error (hiding the error message), and fall back to `lsb_release -cs` in that case:

```
lsb_release -csu 2> /dev/null || lsb_release -cs
```

Comment: Annoyingly, Mint sylvia drops the `-u`.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu's "upstream" is Debian and so

```
$ cat /etc/debian_version
stretch/sid
$
```